# Augmenting external interface

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to augment the [types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/convict) of [convict](https://github.com/mozilla/node-convict). Currently the definitions export `convict` using:

```js
namespace convict { ... }
interface convict { ... }
declare var convict: convict;
export = convict;
```

So I augmented the interface (in `./types/convict/index.d.ts`):

```js
declare module 'convict' {
  interface convict {
    <T>(
      config: convict.Schema<T> | string,
      options?: { env: Record<string, string> }
    ): convict.Config<T>;
  }
}
```

However this interface is not picked up when importing the default export `convict`. It seems this is caused by `export = convict` and `declare var convict: convict`. However I can import the augmented interface directly:

```js
// Default import fails - same interface as @types/convict
import convict from 'convict';

// Import interface directly is ok - convict interface is augmented
import { convict } from 'convict';
```

Can anyone help me understand why `export = convict` and `declare var convict: convict` ignores the augmented interface?

Comment: Since the module uses export assignment, you can't really augment it unless it provides some augmentation points (like `express` does). With export assignment what is in the module is basically private and only what is in the exported identifier is public. So you can't augment what you can't see.

Comment: Thanks for your help this makes sense. Regarding the express augmentation points, are you referring to declarations inside `declare global {}`?

Comment: Yup exactly those, since those are in the global namespace they can be augmented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Titian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56940235/augmenting-external-interface?noredirect=1#comment100420845_56940235) this is not possible because the export assignment limits the visibility to only the exported declaration - the other declarations are private and so they can't be augmented.